# Angular 2 [disabled] is not working

Tags: angular

I need to disable the **Add Hero** button when there is nothing on the text box.Can you tell me why this is not working ?

```
<form novalidate #f="ngForm">

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">{{hero.name}}</li>
</ul>

<label>New hero name: <input required #newHeroName /></label>
<button (click)="addHero(newHeroName.value); newHeroName.value=''" 
         [disabled]="f.invalid">Add Hero</button>

</form>
```

Plunker is here : [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/KGzje3JP0of5MmXvgeyJ?p=preview)

The file is this : `app/toh/hero-list.component.html`

[image]

Comment: Why does this need a Plunker with ~20 files? Plunker provides a clean Angular2 template to start with. I gave up because I didn't find the button in the plunker.

Comment: it shows only one button no ? please see the image @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Yes, but why do you need ***twenty files*** to get the point across?  Surely you can pare this down to like, two.

Comment: Oh... please wait .. @Makoto

Comment: I have reduced it 50% now.can you give me a support now ? @Makoto

Comment: the plnkr is not working anymore !

Comment: now it is working.please see that @5313M

Comment: I have reduced the content.Can you see that now ? @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add `(input)="null"` like

```
<input #newHeroName required (input)="null"
```

then Angular will run change detection after every `input` event.

Without it Angular won't recognize any change.

With

```
<button [disabled]="!newHeroName.value">Add Hero</button>
```

you get the buttons enable/disable set depending on the input being empty or not.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0ZrCFNUQg1VN7VjCnSou?p=preview)

[image]

Comment: still it is not working no ? your plunker also not showing what you're saying ? Where am I wrong ? please see that .

Comment: No idea what you mean. The button is disabled when the input is empty, and enabled when not empty. Is this not what you want?

Comment: yes that is what I want.but your plunker is not showing it no ? is that wrong one ?

Comment: Works for me. No idea what your problem is.

Comment: you have added this line only no ? `<div>disabled: {{f.invalid}}</div>`. on your plunk ?

Comment: @Günter: fyi - for me your plunker is also not working; Still able to hit button when no input is entered; Tested it twice

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer your plunker is not uptodate, here is the solution @Sampath `<label>New hero name:
    <input #newHeroName required (input)="null" />
  </label>
  <button (click)="addHero(newHeroName.value); newHeroName.value=''" [disabled]="!newHeroName.value">Add Hero</button>`

Comment: Seems to be a Plunker problem. See above how the code in the plunker looks when I open it.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend.I have updated it manually and now it's working :)

Answer (score 3):

To be more viewed; here's @GünterZöchbauer Solution since the plnkr cannot be edited :

just change those parts as follows:

```
<label>New hero name: 
<input #newHeroName required (input)="null" /> </label> 
<button (click)="addHero(newHeroName.value); newHeroName.value=''" 
 [disabled]="!newHeroName.value">Add Hero</button>
```

**PLEASE CHECK @GünterZöchbauer's ANSWER**

Comment: yep,Thanks a lot for your support too :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your input to this, then it works:

```
...
<input #newHeroName type="text" 
class="form-control" 
id="name" required [(ngModel)]="model" name="name" ></label>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code as below, it works with your plunker:

```
<label>New hero name: <input [ngModel]="newHeroName.value" #newHeroName required name="heroname"/></label>
<button (click)="addHero(newHeroName.value); newHeroName.value=''" 
     [disabled]="!f.form.valid">Add Hero</button>
```